# Using “das heißt” to express consequence?

Tags: word-usage

I’ve found that *das heißt* can be easily translated as *that means* or *id est* (i.e) and I started to use it quite a lot. My only doubt is the following.

I’m not sure if I can use it not only to explain further or in a different way what I’m trying to say, but also for consequence. Let’s have a look to this example:

> Today I feel very sick. *This means* I’ll stay at home. [*for this reason / as a consequence*]

If not, what are the best alternatives to use in this kind of sentences?

Comment: You example sentence does not contain “das heißt”.

Comment: @CarstenS yepp you are right. I just didn't have time to look for a correct german version, since also I was not sure about it... can you help me with the translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use *Das heißt …* in this case.

An alternative stressing that you are talking about a consequence could be *Soll heißen …*

But be aware that the latter can be perceived as fairly strong/direct — if you said this e.g. to your employer, it would mean that you are not apologising for having to stay at home, but that you **will** stay at home, no matter what they think.

Comment: However, _soll heißen_ is more colloquial in tone.

Comment: @chirlu: I disagree. *Das heißt* is more colloquial (at least in Austria).

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ah, interesting. Then I should restrict my statement above to Germany. Anyone who can report from Switzerland?

Comment: @chirlu Please don't restrict it to Germany, but to your region. I disagree, too, and *my German* has nothing in common with Austrian German whatsoever.

Comment: @Em1: Now _that’s_ even more interesting. I should probably make a question about this.

Comment: I would say "soll heißen" and "das heißt" are both colloquial in their usage to express a consequence.

Answer (score 2):

*Das heißt* does indeed state a consequence of the first part of the sentence (or the prior sentence), but only in the meaning of it being the only and, implied, logical consequence.

If there are several possible consequences (i.e. I feel sick, so I will stay at home, or I will come in later, or I will go to a docter and see what he says), it might be better to use something like *deshalb* or *daher*:

> Ich fühle mich nicht gut, ich bleibe daher zu Hause.